# Error trying to insert array node object XDMP-CHILDDUPNAME?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I've read all the documentation around using XQuery to manipulate JSON documents and adding nodes and adding elements to arrays using xdmp:insert-xxx but I'm trying to create a new object with an array of values to an existing array and can't seem to figure it out.

I would like to add the following object to the root node of my json document.

```
{
 "A" : [ "B", "C" ]
}
```

When I try,

```
xdmp:node-insert-child( $doc/object-node(), object-node{ "ConfiscatedItems" : array-node{ "calculator", "welding iron" } }/ConfiscatedItems )
```

I receive the XDMP-CHILDDUPNAME Object nodes cannot have two children with the same name

My end object is to say if I had a document like;

```
{
   "f": "g",
   "h": 1,
   "q": [ 1, 2 ]
}
```

I would like it to look like;

```
{
   "f": "g",
   "h": 1,
   "q": [ 1, 2 ],
   "A": [ "B", "C" ]
}
```

I can do this in two steps by create a new text node called 'A' and the using `xdmp:node-replace()` with the array, but I want to do this in one step, not two. This is mainly because I'm creating generic code that uses `xdmp:value()` to execute tasks meaning I have limits around transactions and can't do this in two steps in the same transaction.
Can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the XPath `/ConfiscatedItems` that is addressing the named property with an array-node, it will return a sequence of the array items. Those items will have the same name and will result in the (confusing if you don't understand what is happening) error message **XDMP-CHILDDUPNAME**.

It can be helpful to use [`xdmp:describe()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:describe) to get a better idea of what is being selected for JSON nodes.

You want to return the array-node, not the items in the array. So, change your XPath from:

```
/ConfiscatedItems
```

to:

```
/array-node("ConfiscatedItems")
```

Or, to match the example JSON you posted `/array-node("A")`

Comment: Thanks. A bit obvious when you think about it. I wasn't thinking.